# How to define NumberForm in LegendLabel?

Tags: legending, labeling, geography, geographics

To start:

```
FLcounties = 
  AdministrativeDivisionData[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Florida", "UnitedStates"}], 
   "Subdivisions"];

FLcountiespop = 
  AdministrativeDivisionData[#, "Population"] & /@ FLcounties;

ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[FLcounties -> FLcountiespop]];

FLPopulationMap = 
 GeoRegionValuePlot[ds, GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 600, 
  GeoLabels -> (Tooltip[#1, 
      Row[{#2, ": ", EntityValue[#2, "PopulationDensity"]}]] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[# > 2500000, Purple, 
      If[# > 2000000, Red, 
       If[# > 1500000, Orange, 
        If[# > 1000000, Yellow, If[# > 500000, Green, Blue]]]]] &), 
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
      PlotLegends -> 
       BarLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
        LegendLabel -> "Population", 
        LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 16]]]
```

The above should build a population map for all the counties in Florida; accompanied by a bar legend.  If you now look at the bar legend of this map; what I' m attempting is to modify the NumberForm of the bar legend; so that the population values appear as:
      2,500,000; 2,000,000; 1,500,000; 1,000,000; 500,000
instead of in exponential form as above.
I have attempted substituting:

```
LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 16]
```

above with:

```
LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3], Black, Bold, 
    FontSize -> 16]]
```

or

```
LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3], 
Bold, Black, 16] &)
```

but, I get the following error message : 
  "An improperly formatted directive with head NumberForm was
encountered."
I thank you for any help that you could provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the (undocumented) option `"Ticks"` in `BarLegend`:

```
BarLegend[Automatic, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
    LegendLabel -> "Population",
    "Ticks" -> Map[{#, NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3]} &, 100000 Range[5, 25, 5]],
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 16]]]
```

[image]

You can also use `Ticks` in place of `"Ticks"`.

Comment: Thank you @kglr, I accept your answer! Thank you also for your feedback when you add that this option is undocumented.  I notice that when I use either "Ticks" or Ticks (as you suggested); the word Ticks turns red as if it is not part of the Bar Legend repertoire of options.  But, the important thing is that this option works.

Comment: @Gilmar, thank you for the accept. BTW, may I suggest you revisit your previous questions and see if any answers are worth accepting.

Answer (score 0):

The following is added to review the above amendment of the legend and to add county names to the map (for the sake of completeness):

```
FLcounties = 
  AdministrativeDivisionData[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Florida", "UnitedStates"}], 
   "Subdivisions"];

FLcountiespop = 
  AdministrativeDivisionData[#, "Population"] & /@ FLcounties;

ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[FLcounties -> FLcountiespop]];

FLPopulationMap = 
 GeoRegionValuePlot[ds, GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 600, 
  GeoLabels -> (Tooltip[#1, 
      Row[{#2, ": ", EntityValue[#2, "PopulationDensity"]}]] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[# > 2500000, Purple, 
      If[# > 2000000, Red, 
       If[# > 1500000, Orange, 
        If[# > 1000000, Yellow, If[# > 500000, Green, Blue]]]]] &), 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
    LegendLabel -> "Population", 
    "Ticks" -> 
     Map[{#, NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3]} &, 
      100000 Range[5, 25, 5]], 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 16]]]
```

The following steps are added to produce a map of Florida counties with their capitalized county names:

```
countynames = EntityValue[FLcounties, "Name"];

countyshortnames = StringDrop[#, -31] & /@ countynames[[All]];

countycapitalizednames = ToUpperCase[countyshortnames]

loc = EntityValue[FLcounties, "Position"];

MapOfFloridaWithCountyNames = 
  GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], 
    Polygon /@ FLcounties, 
    Table[GeoMarker[loc[[j]], 
      Style[countycapitalizednames[[j]], TextAlignment -> Center, 
       Black, FontSize -> 9, Bold, FontFamily -> "Pallatino"], 
      "Scale" -> 1], {j, 1, Length@countycapitalizednames}]}, 
   GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 1200];

FinalFLMap = 
 Show[MapOfFloridaWithCountyNames, FLPopulationMap, 
  GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

To export the final map; define your working directory:

```
setDir := 
 Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, 
   SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]

path = setDir

Export["Map_FL_Counties_Population_with_County_Names.png", FinalFLMap]
```

The map should look like this:

[image: Map of Florida Population with County Names]